# Wrong Rotation-Matrix when rotating around Z-Axis?

Tags: c#, wpf, math, matrix, rotation

I'm tracking Glyphs and try to display a 3D-object on top of them.
They return a TransformationMatrix with a guess on their orientation. This works nicely in the AForge Gratf Glyph Recognition Studio.
There is also a
[blog-entry on the topic here](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/gratf_ar/)

[image]

Somehow the orientation of my rotation seems off as soon as I rotate the glyph around the Z-axis. **Why are all X- and Y-axis rotations mirrored when I rotate the glyph 180° around the Z-axis?**

**I made a short video illustrating my problem here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN1erbJr9JY&feature=youtu.be**

```
  Matrix4x4 gm = glyphData.TransformationMatrix;

  // turn left-handed matrix in right-handed       
  Matrix3D rightHanded = new Matrix3D(gm.V00, gm.V02, gm.V01, 0,
                                              gm.V20, gm.V22, gm.V32, 0,
                                              gm.V10, gm.V12, gm.V11, 0,
                                              gm.V30, gm.V32, gm.V31, 1);

MatrixTransform3D _transform3D = new MatrixTransform3D(rightHanded);
_transformGroup.Children.Add(_transform3D);
Cube3D.Transform = _transformGroup;  // add it to ModelVisual3D
```

This is the scene-setup in the XAML-file:

```
  <Viewport3D ClipToBounds="False">
  <Viewport3D.Camera>        
       <PerspectiveCamera LookDirection="0,0,1" UpDirection="0,1,0" Position="0,0,-30" />
   </Viewport3D.Camera>

   <ModelVisual3D x:Name="Cube3D"   >
   ...
```

Comment: It may be useful to ask a specific question in this case. The implied "huh?" may not translate...and the video I now see doesn't exactly clarify. It's obvious it's not right but it's not obvious when the difference occurs.

Comment: The problem happens when I rotate the Glyph 180°. All following rotations are mirrored.

Comment: I annotated the video to explain the problem.